# C++/CLI : array<doube>^ VS double[]

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

Concerning performance, what will be the difference between using managed

```
array<double>^ tab1 = new array<double>(n)
```

versus unmanaged

```
double* tab2 = new double[n]
```

?

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: As long as you compile the code with /clr, you code isn't unmanaged ;) you get somehow interpreted code. And as I see the emitted code doesn't really differ a lot from the array<> usage.

Comment: @Lucas : actually I observe a 40% performance gain using double[]... The question would be "why?"